# Cannot login GeoServer after choosing to install as service?

Tags: geoserver, installation, geoserver-rest-api

I work on windows7. While installing GeoServer, I selected the 'install as a service' option. As I know when I installed GeoServer as a service, geoserver is already running. But I nagative to Web Administration Interface by url:

> *localhost:8089/geoserver/web/*

I can't log in by username and password. It have an announcement "Invalid username/password combination". Do anyone know this problem and fix it. Help me, please!

Comment: Have you followed this [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/webadmin/basics.html)? Are you sure you have access to the security folder?

Comment: Which GeoServer version? Which java version? When you run the installer were you logged in as admin? Did you install into "Program Files" or into some other directory? I  recommend to install GeoServer 2.6-RC1 from http://geoserver.org/release/dev because it has some improvements in the Windows installer.

Comment: I run manuallly geoserver before. This is the fist time I run geoserver as a service. I set Full control security to install folder but I still can not log in. what I have to do?

Comment: You should not need to do anything more. If you do, the installer does not work as it should. If you find why it fails you can make a bug report for Geoserver and installer will be fixed. My questions try to help you to find why it does not work for you. Did you let the installer to create a new data_dir or did you use an existing one?

Comment: I use the stable set up <i>geoserver-2.5.2.exe</i>, and jre7. I don't know <i>When you run the installer were you logged in as admin?</i> what is mean. I do not set username as admin, and password as geoserver. I set username and password by my name. I install in "Progame Files".

Comment: Thanks @user30184 . I removed that version I installed and set up GeoServer 2.6-RC1 as you recommend. It worked. But why? Can you tell me?

Comment: No, I should repeat all what you did with the same versions and try to find the differences. I know that the old installer could not raise user rights of directories which were inside Program Files or Program Files (x86) on Windows 7 but you wrote you had done that manually.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16581/discussion-between-ll2-and-user30184).

Answer (score 1):

For the GeoServer version 2.6-RC1 some work was done for making the Windows installer to work on Windows 7. The old installer version which worked well on Windows XP could not raise user rights of the GeoServer installation directory and data_dir on Windows 7 if directories were placed into "Program Files" or "Program Files (x86)". Installation into other directories like C:\geoserver was successful.

It is not sure if that was the reason why user @LL2 could not login to the GeoServer admin utility but anyway, installing GS 2.6-RC1 solved the issue.